# In App Purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am new in iPhone development.

if i want to buy only an image within the application through Apple - In App purchase Payment mode. So what would be the method for this?

NOTE: Dont Want to buy the whole Application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Refer [this](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/) blog of In App Purchase

Also refer the [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

You keep the image locked and ask the user to make an in app purchase for it to unlock.